# How to use drop down menu in uitextfield in ios?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to implement a drop down menu in text field in ios.

For this i have been trying to implement this solution for text field https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu

Above menu bar works great for nav bar but unable to add it on text fields.

Note : I can't use uipickerview in my case .

Comment: If u need to provide some options (instead of autocomplete text), you can use a UIActionSheet here.

Comment: @Nishant `UIActionSheet` is a **very** bad idea. It resigns the current `firstResponder`. Very bad UX-wise.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer: One more thing to add here then. For that particular textfield, you will need to implement `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;` *// return NO to disallow editing.*

Comment: @Nishant, you're right about implementing `UITextFieldDelegate` methods, but only to change results as and when text field changes. Editing should not be disabled. How would you feel if you could only change one character at a time in Google Search? I'm talking in terms of UX only.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer: You are right. But that is called **Autocomplete** feature, whereas here the question is about **drop down menu** with default options. warzone_fz has given a similar link in the question itself.

Comment: Personally I don't like the dropdown menu in iOS since it's not a part of standard UI design in iOS. I feel that UIPickerView should be preferred as inputView on any textField.

Comment: @Nishant. You're absolutely right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply add table and in `beginEditing` of `UITextField` Show table and in `endEditing` hide table and set table Height according content size